# How can i post my json data to the body of a request in universal windows platform (uwp)

Tags: uwp

```
// This is the submit button
```

private void book_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {

// My json result, i'm sending this to an Api

```
 string json = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(objnewobject, Newtonsoft.Json.Formatting.Indented);  

// My API url that will take the json value to the database

   string url = "http://62.173.41.5:7500/NNRAService/webresources/customerResources/makeBooking?";  

// Tested but not working 

    HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
            HttpRequestMessage req = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Post, ToString());  
                req.Content = new StringContent(json, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");  
                var response = await client.SendAsync(req);  
                string responseString = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
```

}

Comment: `StatusCode: 500, ReasonPhrase: 'Internal Server Error'` means something went wrong server side, there might be nothing wrong anymore with your POST in c#. Try to access the logs of the webservice to find out why a `500 error` occurred

Comment: The service provider said my data was not submitted correctly, that's why i have the error

Comment: He said maybe i'm not sending it to the body

Comment: we have tested the service with android and ios version of the application and it works fine, help me out with it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `PostAsync` method. Sample code:

```cs
using (var client = new HttpClient())
{
    var jsonContent = new StringContent(json, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
    return await client.PostAsync(uri, jsonContent);
}
```

Be sure to dispose the `HttpClient` after using it to clean up properly (this is done here by the `using` construct).

Comment: it doesn't work for me, see my result above. please help me. don't forget that i'm sending it to the body, not head. thanks in anticipation.

Answer (score 0):

```
// This is my code, but it doesn't work. dont forget that i want to send it to the body
private async void theData()
    {
        Uri url = new Uri("http://62.173.41.5:7500/NNRAService/webresources/customerResources/makeBooking?");
        using (var client = new HttpClient())
        {
            var jsonContent = new StringContent(json, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
            var answer = await client.PostAsync(url, jsonContent);
            Debug.WriteLine(answer);
        }
    }

//My response from server

StatusCode: 500, ReasonPhrase: 'Internal Server Error', Version: 1.1, Content: System.Net.Http.StreamContent, Headers:
```

{
  Connection: close
  Date: Fri, 12 May 2017 14:58:03 GMT
  Content-Length: 1572
  Content-Type: text/html
}

Comment: As this is not an answer please edit your question to include this part of your further analysis of the problem

Comment: This is what i got after i tested the first solution